# I want check whether if prop count >0 send message else no prop found

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$agent_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$this->load->model('agent_model');
$res = $this->agent_model->agentsjoin($agent_id);
foreach($res as $k=>$v){
    if($res[$k]->prop_count>0){
        echo "send message";
    }else{
        echo "no prop found";
    }
}
```

The $res has a output of agent_id and prop_count

Comment: $res is object or an array?? Please post it.

Comment: What is your question? Your code seems incomplete. Do you want to know how to send a message or how to do the check?

Comment: Is an array and this is what $res contains

Comment: {"agent_id":null,"sum(prop_count)":null},{"agent_id":"101004","sum(prop_count)":null},{"agent_id":"101005","sum(prop_count)":null},{"agent_id":"101006","sum(prop_count)":null},{"agent_id":"101013","sum(prop_count)":null},{"agent_id":"101014","sum(prop_count)":null},{"agent_id":"101015","sum(prop_count)":"2671"},{"agent_id":"101016","sum(prop_count)":null},{"agent_id":"101017","sum(prop_count)":"677"},{"agent_id":"101018","sum(prop_count)":"343"},

Comment: @KLP - could you edit that into your question?

Comment: this is what my $res contains,now i want to check for each agent id.If agents prop_count greater than zero the output should be "sms sent".Else "no prop" found,,,,,can someone please send me the code

Answer (score 2):

If $res is an object you might want to try this code:

```
$agent_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$this->load->model('agent_model');
$res = $this->agent_model->agentsjoin($agent_id);
foreach ($res as $k => $v) {
    if ($v->prop_count > 0) {
        echo "send message";
    } else {
        echo "no prop found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dees040 but i am getting error like "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array".

Comment: @KLP i changed the answer, which might fix the error.

Comment: This is my new error "Undefined property: stdClass::$prop_count"

Comment: Hi Dees040 can you answer please?

Comment: still no Call to undefined method stdClass::sum()

Comment: that error is probably do to with the stdClass or that $prop_count is not actually set. @KLP

Comment: @KLP Your modal is not returing the correct data, it's returing some kind of SQL function I guess